# Pass parameters to messages from resource bundle to components other than **h:outputFormat**

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, facelets, resourcebundle

Is there a convenient way to pass parameters to messages from resource bundle to components other than **h:outputFormat**?

For instance, this is legal:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{myBundle['parametricMessage']}">
    <f:param value="#{myBundle['someParameterValue']}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

But I need it for a button, like this (which won't work):

```
<h:commandButton value="#{myBundle['parametricMessage']}">
    <f:param value="#{myBundle['someParameterValue']}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

*Of course, I can use link instead of button, and I can make it through a property in a managed bean, but in this question I'm seeking for a **convenient** way to use the button...*

I'm using RichFaces 3.3.3, JSF2, facelets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this approach ?

[EL expression allow you to define a function](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaio) .You first define a EL expression 's function , which  accepts a  resource bundle , its message key and placeholder 's parameter and output the resolved message .

```
public static String geti18nMsg(ResourceBundle bundle ,String msgKey, String paramValue ) {
    String  msgValue = bundle.getString(msgKey);
    MessageFormat   messageFormat = new MessageFormat(msgValue);
    Object[] args = {paramValue};
    return messageFormat.format(args);
}
```

Then call this function to get the  resolved message in the `<h:commandButton>` :

```
<h:commandButton value="#{f:geti18nMsg(myBundle , parametricMessage, someParameterValue)}"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you are using <f:loadBundle> because what you are passing through is a ResouceBundleMap and not a ResouceBundle. If you use <f:loadBundle> you can change the ResouceBundle to Map<String,String> and then you do a .get(msgKey) on it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<h:commandButton>
    <h:outputFormat value="#{myBundle['parametricMessage']}">
        <f:param value="#{myBundle['someParameterValue']}"/>
    </h:outputFormat>
</h:commandButton>
```

Btw, this does what you want and also avoids having to write backing bean code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't find good answer on that, so the question will remain open. 
A good practice I've discovered, is to have a special class that represents each resource bundle (that has parametric stuff), and to transfer all the message formation, and working with context there (like, acquire locale from FacesContext, get a ResourceBundle, apply parameters, etc). And finally to provide access to a singleton of such service class from your ManagedBean.

This requires some additional work to be done, but solves the problem and is worth of the time.