# JSF2 button value parameterized?

Tags: jsf-2, properties, parameters

Using JSF2 markup, is it possible to pass properties parameters to button value? I am aware of `<h:outputFormat>` tag but I need it to be a button. I am interested more in something like below.

My XHTML code:

```html
<h:button value="#{webCommonMessages['notifications']}" outcome="...">
    <f:param value="1"/>
</h:button>
```

My webCommonMessages bundle:

```
notifications=Notifications available: ({0})
```

This of course does not work but is there any solution/workaround for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, JSF doesn't provide built-in functionality to get what you want, so basically you have three ways to go:

1. create a custom EL function to get the substituted value, as described in [Pass parameters to messages from resource bundle to components other than **h:outputFormat**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5726405/1820286),
2. create a custom component that exports the substituted value as a request scope variable visible in EL context, as hinted in [How to use Parameterized MessageFormat with non-Value attributes of JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12010175/1820286) or
3. use the solution proposed in utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) maintained by BalusC as per the component [`<o:outputFormat>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/outputFormat) that effectively incorporates in itself the second way.

So, if you are up to the third way, which I personally warmly recommend, the solution is basically as follows:

```
<o:outputFormat value="#{webCommonMessages['notifications']}" var="t">
    <f:param value="1" />
</o:outputFormat>
<h:button value="#{t}" outcome="..." />
```

Using OmniFaces in a JSF project is ridiculously easy and is descibed [on its homepage](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/), but to repeat: just add its jar to /WEB-INF/lib folder of your web application (or include it as a maven dependency) and add a proper namespace in your facelet views, like `xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"`.

It's also worth adding that my initial answer was wrong. It erroneously assumed that nesting JSF's `<h:outputFormat>` will render the necessary HTML element. Still, it is true for a plain navigational link, as provided in JSF by, for example, `<h:link>`, and is to be used like:

```
<h:link outcome="...">
    <h:outputFormat value="#{webCommonMessages['notifications']}">
        <f:param value="1" />
    </h:outputFormat>
</h:link>
```

---

You wrongly assumed that `<f:param>` nested in `<h:button>` will be incorporated in your message from resource bundle. It is used to append query parameters to the generated URL. Instead you need to use [`<h:outputFormat>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputFormat.html) tag for your purpose nested within your button and, thus, not specifying its `value` attribute:

```
<h:button outcome="...">
    <h:outputFormat value="#{webCommonMessages['notifications']}">
        <f:param value="1" />
    </h:outputFormat>
</h:button>
```

Comment: Just tried that and it rendered empty button (no value) and text message from outputFormat next to it. What I need is button with parametrized value.

Comment: I will use ``h:link`` first, but OmniFaces looks promising. Many thanks for help.